# Figure-8 is not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Define the figure-8 curve $S$ to be the image of the smooth map $\beta : (-\pi,\pi) → \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\beta(t)=(\sin 2t, \sin t)$.

I am trying to prove that $S$ is not an embedded (or regular) submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The thing is, I am teaching myself differential geometry, and the chapter on submanifolds has been very difficult, so I would appreciate it if someone verified that I was thinking correctly about this stuff.

Here are my proofs. I believe the 2nd proof is the standard approach.

**Proof 1**: First of all, note that $S$ is an immersed submanifold, with the submanifold topology inherited from the immersion $\beta$. If $S$ were also an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then because $\beta$ is smooth, we may restrict the codomain to $S$ and conclude that $\beta$ is also smooth as a map onto its image $S$, but $S$ is not even continuous with its submanifold topolgy, let alone smooth. This is a contradiction, so $S$ cannot be an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Proof 2** (sketch): By assuming $S$ is an embedded submanifold, we may use the local slice condition to arrive at a contradiction by considering the number of components, which ought to be preserved by homeomorphisms but isn't here.

*Edit*: So it turns out that Proof 1 does not work (see comments). I might try reworking the argument and editing the question with it, but ultimately, it seems only Proof 2 is correct.

Comment: Why do you think $\beta$ is not continuous?

Comment: Wait, right, I got confused. If $\beta$ is extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$ THEN it won't be continuous, but $\beta$ is definitely continuous. So my proof doesn't work. *facepalm* This was proved in the book. I can write down the proof for that if you want.

Comment: The map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $t \mapsto (\sin 2t , \sin t)$ is certainly continuous.

Comment: Yes, but I am referring to the map $ \mathbb{R} → S $ given by $\beta(t)=(\sin 2t, \sin t)$ where $S$ has the topology induced by the smooth immersion $\beta$.

Comment: Suppose $F : N → M$ is an injective smooth immersion, then $S:=F(N)$ has a unique topology and smooth structure making it into an immersed submanifold of $M$ such that $F:N→S$ is a diffeomorphism even.

Comment: This topology is given as follows: a subset $U$ of $S$ is open iff $F^{-1}(U)$ is open in $N$. In particular, the map $\beta$ above is an injective immersion, so $S$ has a unique topology and smooth structure turning it into an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: With this topology, the map $G:\mathbb{R} → S$ is not continuous at $\pi$ because $\beta^{-1} \circ G$ is not continuous there.